# How do I search all revisions of a file in a SubVersion repository?

Tags: svn

I'd like to `grep` all revisions of a file for a string.  e.g. to find when a function was added or removed.

Is there a "simple" way to do this? (i.e. a single `bash` command line would be nice.)  Doing a manual binary search by checking out revisions and testing individually seems too tedious and error prone.

If I was smart enough to commit the change with a useful description then I can `grep` the log with something like:

```
svn log myfile.c | grep my_func
```

This doesn't provide a revision number though, so I suspect there's a better way to do that too.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I wrote a script to do it

TYpical usage:

```
perl searchrev.pl Import.php setImportStatus

----------------------------------------------------------------------
r19565 | johnf | 2009-06-24 14:33:00 +0100 (Wed, 24 Jun 2009) | 1 line
----------------------------------------------------------------------
line 60 $this->setImportStatus($entity_id, $entity_attr_id);
---------------------------------------------------------------------
r13722 | john | 2008-03-10 17:06:14 +0000 (Mon, 10 Mar 2008) | 1 line
---------------------------------------------------------------------
line 70 $this->setImportStatus($entity_id, $entity_attr_id);
---------------------------------------------------------------------
r11692 | paul | 2007-05-23 10:55:45 +0100 (Wed, 23 May 2007) | 1 line
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Not found
---------------------------------------------------------------------
r11691 | paul | 2007-05-23 10:36:26 +0100 (Wed, 23 May 2007) | 1 line
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Not found
---------------------------------------------------------------------
r11683 | paul | 2007-05-23 09:04:29 +0100 (Wed, 23 May 2007) | 1 line
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Not found
```

Here's the script, easy to hack for your own purposes

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $file=$ARGV[0];
my $pattern=$ARGV[1];

my @history=`svn log "$file"`;
foreach (@history)
{
    chomp;
    if (m/^r(\d+)/)
    {
        my $revision=$1;
        my $sep='-' x length($_);

        print "$sep\n$_\n$sep\n";

        my @code=`svn cat -r $revision "$file"`;
        my $lineno=0;
        my $found=0;
        foreach my $line (@code)
        {
            $lineno++;
            if ($line=~m/$pattern/)
            {
                $line=~s/^\s+//;
                print "line $lineno $line";
                 $found=1;
            }
        }

        print "Not found\n" unless ($found);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about starting at the current revision and then only grepping in the diffs?

Comment: For the second time in a few days, a search has led me to a SO question I asked years ago! Thanks again for your answer :)

Comment: If you don't have `perl` installed here's one that only uses `egrep`: https://gist.github.com/lapo-luchini/8666153

Comment: really great script, thanx a lot! We have a similar and very much used functionality for MacProgrammingWorkshop (MPW - ancient!), and this tool might very well show that "this new svn thing" is not that bad after all...

Comment: I have found this script very useful, and extended it with `--until-found` `--until-lost` (stops at highest matching/non-matching revision) `--diff`(show differences lowest revision found and previous, if stopping for `--until-*`) and `--firstline` (show only first matching line in a revision).

Comment: @PJTraill, is your version available in some public version control system?

Comment: @Richlv: I am sorry to say it is not, and I no longer even have access to it, as I made it at work and have since retired – but these functions are pretty straightforward to implement, for someone who knows a little perl.

Answer (score 7):

The ["annotate/blame" command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html) does not do exactly what you want, but it could help:

> svn blame — Show author and revision information in-line for the specified files or URLs.

```
 $ svn blame http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/test/readme.txt
 3      sally This is a README file.
 5      harry You should read this.
```

So, you should be able to find out who added a function. As for finding out who deleted a function, no idea.

Answer (score 4):

This is a command to search for revisions of a file containing a string:

```
svn log -l 30 -q FILENAME | grep ^r | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | while read rev; do
    svn cat -$rev FILENAME | grep -c PATTERN && svn info FILENAME@$rev
done
```

Answer (score 3):

With a Subversion 1.6 server and its `mod_dav_svn` you can specify the revision number via a GET parameter:

```
http://host/repos/path?r=20
```

So you can easily `wget` your files in all revisions and then `diff` them.

Source: [SVN 1.6 changelog](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.6_releasenotes.html#historical-uris)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that you want to do will be difficult. I would normally suggest using svn diff or svn cat, but there is (as far as I know) no way to get the revision number inline with the code output.

On the second question, if you're looking for a specific user, you can use

```
svn log | grep -A 2 username
```

which will give you two extra lines after every matched line (-A = "after"). If you don't have very long log messages, you can use

```
svn log | grep -B 2 search_string
```

which will similarly print two lines before (-B) each matched line. (Which should hopefully be enough to give you the revision number.) I am absolutely certain that there is a better way with AWK to give you the revision numbers in line with the log messages, but I'm tired and I can't think of it right now. :D

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that's not easily possible. I'd write a small script that retrieves each changeset for the file in question and then grep through the diff for the string. Then it's as simple as printing the current revision number :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [pySVN](http://pysvn.tigris.org/) + the python [diff tools](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) to do this, while it is not bash, it maybe worth considering if you use this function on a more regular basis.  It is a version of the [wget solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118051/how-do-i-search-all-revisions-of-a-file-in-a-subversion-repository/1118316#1118316) but would have a nicer interface, well if you build it :)