# svn repository search engine - any new updates

Tags: svn, repository, search-engine

Looking on Google and Stack I don't see much in the way for SVN Repository Search Engine functionality and I wanted to know if there are any projects out there either highly recommended or under the radar that show some real promise.

We have a huge repo of Legacy code that is cumbersome to look though and wanted to implement some sort of searching capability. I did see some related SO questions but all the projects don't seem to be actively worked on.

Looking for:

- Free or Low cost ( no monthly but would be willing to buy if the price is reasonable )
- Most of our code base is PHP/Python/Ruby with some Java
- Ability to search Trunk/Branches/Tags and revisions

Related:

- [SVN Repository Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254214/svn-repository-search)

Answer (score 0):

Use git-svn to import it into Git, then take advantage of Git's powerful search tools, eg.

`git log -S'ADDED-OR-REMOVED-TEXT' --author='Joe User' --since='last year'`

The `git-svn` import may be run incrementally to keep the imported repository up-to-date.

[Full git-log manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html).

Comment: will this also search multiple repos as once?