# Searching strings in remote SVN Repository in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, search, eclipse-plugin, subversive

I have to access many files in SVN Repository on a remote server. I use these file through Eclipse. (Using SVN plugin)
Now i want to search **a particular string within all those files** located on remote server.

Any help with that??

Comment: Can you download the repo locally?

Comment: Yaa.. but the files keep changing (added, deleted, edited). Also that is a huge database. Downloading locally will be the last thing i want to do.

Comment: Some quick searching on google reveals some programs that do this. I'd list them, but there's too many for that.

Comment: Give me something at least. I ll try searching myself though.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the Eclipse plugins for svn (Subclipse and Subversive) provides that capability; I don't even think the svn server provides a command or API to do it. TortiseSVN doesn't appear to have the capability, either. However, you might get some ideas from [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254214/svn-repository-search).