# Search SVN for specific files

Tags: python, svn

I am trying to write a Python script to search a (very large) SVN repository for specific files (ending with .mat). Usually I would use os.walk() to walk through a directory and then search for the files with a RegEx. Unfortunately I can't use os.walk() for a repository, since it is not a local directory.

Does anyone know how to do that? The repository is too large to download, so I need to search for it "online".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered switching to VisualSVN Server? VisualSVN Server has a web repository search. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20397195/761095 and this https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#asf

Answer (score 1):

Something like

`svn ls -R REPO-ROOT | grep PATTERN`

will help