# Does SourceForge have a Subversion repository search feature?

Tags: search, svn, sourceforge

Is there a way to search the Subversion repository of a project hosted on SourceForge? I see that I can Browse Commits/Files but I'd like to perform a full text search. If no such feature exist, is there a workaround like a way to export the entire SVN repo (I'm not the project owner)?

An example, I'm a user (not project owner) trying to find changes involving the ORB_ID_STRING literal on the omniORB project.

I unsuccessfully attempted to answer this question by: searching stackoverflow, searching using various Google keywords like "sourceforge how to search SVN".  I also submitted this SourceForge support ticket: https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/site-support/20997/.

Comment: did you try svnsearcher? it used to be a Java binary with an indexer and a client or webapplication for then searching into it. If you are using VisualSVNServer there already is a search bar in it.

Comment: also have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254214/svn-repository-search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the reply I got from SourceForge Support on Monday July 20, 2020:

> Dave Brondsema -
> Hello,
>
> We do not currently offer an option to search the full text of a code repository. You
> can download the repository yourself though and do a search yourself. The easiest option
> is to use the "Download Snapshot" link in the upper right of a code repository. Note:
> you probably want to be in the "trunk" folder first or it will be a very large download
> including copies of all the branches and tagged versions of the code. Alternatively, you
> can install SVN on your computer and do an SVN checkout of the repository.
> Sincerely,
> SourceForge Support